# Trimming Mako output

Tags: python, layout, template-engine, mako

I really like the Mako templating system that's used in Pylons and a couple other Python frameworks, and my only complaint is how much WS leaks through even a simple inheritance scheme.

Is there anyway to accomplish below, without creating such huge WS gaps... or packing my code in like I started to do with base.mako?

Otherwise to get a grip on what I'm trying to accomplish with below.

Base is kind of like interface class for all views for the entire application, layout is just a prototype idea for 3-4 different layout files ( tables, pure CSS, etc ), and controller/action is a test to make sure my idea's are sane.

Short summary of question:  How to cut out the WS created in my Mako scheme?

Update: Is not a solution because it involves seeding all of my mako files with \'s
   http://www.makotemplates.org/docs/syntax.html#syntax_newline

/base.mako

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head><%def name="headtags()"></%def>${self.headtags()}</head>
  <body>
    <%def name="header()"></%def>${self.header()}${next.body()}<%def name="footer()"></%def>${self.footer()}
  </body>
</html>
```

/layout.mako

```
<%inherit file="/base.mako"/>
<%def name="headtags()">
   ${parent.headtags()}
   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>
</%def>
<%def name="header()">
  <h1>My Blogination</h1>
</%def>
<div id="content">${next.body()}</div>
```

/controller/action.mako

```
<%inherit file="/layout.mako" />
<%def name="headtags()">    
    <title> Hello world, templating system is 1 percent done</title>
    ${parent.headtags()}
</%def>
Hello ${c.name}!
```

rendered output:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html>
  <head>    
    <title> Hello world, templating system is 1 percent done</title>

   <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/prototype/1.6.0.3/prototype.js"></script>


</head>
  <body>

  <h1>My Blogination</h1>


<div id="content">

Hello Anonymous!

</div>

  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wow, just realized how old this question was, this must have been one of my last projects to use prototype.js

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found my own answer
http://docs.makotemplates.org/en/latest/filtering.html

It still required some trial and error, but using

```
t = TemplateLookup(directories=['/tmp'], default_filters=['trim'])
```

dramatically cut down on whitespace bleed.  Additional savings can be found by checking the compiled template's and looking for any writes that are just pushing ' ' or similar.

Comment: It's unfortunate that this does not fix `def` calls